# Error when downloading Truffle on NPM (1st time was fine but problem when downloading for the 2nd time)

Tags: node.js, npm, truffle

I had no issue downloading truffle for the first time using `npm install truffle` on my terminal. I later removed truffle and node.js from my mac. Now I'm trying to reinstall truffle using the same code and I'm getting this error. Been trying every suggestion I read online and still wouldn't work

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\git\bin\bash.exe
npm ERR! file C:\Program Files (x86)\git\bin\bash.exe
npm ERR! path C:\Program Files (x86)\git\bin\bash.exe
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! bufferutil@4.0.3 install: `node-gyp-build`
npm ERR! spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\git\bin\bash.exe ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the bufferutil@4.0.3 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Any help would be highly appreaciated!

Comment: did you reinstall node too?

Comment: The file and path npm is referring to are Windows style: `C:\Program...`, and npm can't find them, hence the `ENOENT` error. You are on a mac. Are you sure nothing has changed in comparison to the last time you installed this?

Comment: @taimoor yes I did. I installed Nodejs v14.17.5

Comment: @user1984 hmm, that's really weird. Yes, I'm pretty sure nothing has changed since the gap between my first and 2nd installation were just days apart. Any idea how I can fix this?